# How to auto-instantiate a library in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using a really basic library in Codeigniter. In order to use it I need to pass in a number of config parameters using a config function. My library currently requires me to instantiate it before I can call the config, i.e., I have to use it as below:

```
$this->load->library('Library');
$instance = new Library();
$instance->config($configparams);
```

I'd like to use it like standard CodeIgniter libraries:

```
$this->load->library('Library');
$this->library->config($configparams);
```

What do I need to add to the library in order to have it auto-instantiate? The code is as below:

```
class Library {

     function config($configparams){
       ...
     }
}
```

**This is working now. I swear it wasn't working before I posted on SO! Thanks for posts.**

Answer (score 3):

Once you load a class

```
$this->load->library('someclass');
```

Then when use it, need to use lower case, like this:

```
$this->someclass->some_function();
```

Object instances will always be lower case

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html), you should just call it.  So:

```
$this->load->library('Library');
$this->library->config($configparams);
```

But why not just pass `$configparams` to the constructor:

```
$this->load->library('Library', $configparams);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the guide for CodeIgniter -- it's a great resource to learn more about the framework. IMHO, there aren't any good books available on the current version; this is it.

You basically call it like anything else.

```
$this->load->library('Name of Library')
```

Read more here: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcodeigniter.com%2Fuser_guide%2Fgeneral%2Fcreating_libraries.html&ei=tLFUTbz3HI3SsAOYgP2aBg&usg=AFQjCNFo751PYFp5SbqzuZMxGhXwMI8SJA